# Allow connection outside kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, jdbc, ignite

I have this service file in my chart, how can I allow JDBC connection outside kuberiq for example DBeaver? I tried to configure nodeport, but it keeps failing. Can someone assist here?

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: {{ include "ignite.fullname" . }}
      labels:
        app: {{ include "ignite.fullname" . }}
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: jdbc
          port: 11211
          targetPort: 11211
        - name: spi-communication
          port: 47100
          targetPort: 47100
        - name: spi-discovery
          port: 47500
          targetPort: 47500
        - name: jmx
          port: 49112
          targetPort: 49112
        - name: sql
          port: 10800
          targetPort: 10800
        - name: rest
          port: 8080
          targetPort: 8080
        - name: thin-clients
          port: 10900
          targetPort: 10900
      clusterIP: None
      selector:
```

This is the ignite services I want to try to connect even just to create user
`$ kubectl describe svc ignite`

```
Name:              ignite
Namespace:         production
Labels:            app=ignite
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=ignite
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                None
Port:              jdbc  11211/TCP
TargetPort:        11211/TCP
Endpoints:         10.233.112.245:11211,10.233.112.246:11211
Port:              spi-communication  47100/TCP
TargetPort:        47100/TCP
Endpoints:         10.233.112.245:47100,10.233.112.246:47100
Port:              spi-discovery  47500/TCP
TargetPort:        47500/TCP
Endpoints:         10.233.112.245:47500,10.233.112.246:47500
Port:              jmx  49112/TCP
TargetPort:        49112/TCP
Endpoints:         10.233.112.245:49112,10.233.112.246:49112
Port:              sql  10800/TCP
TargetPort:        10800/TCP
Endpoints:         10.233.112.245:10800,10.233.112.246:10800
Port:              rest  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.233.112.245:8080,10.233.112.246:8080
Port:              thin-clients  10900/TCP
TargetPort:        10900/TCP
Endpoints:         10.233.112.245:10900,10.233.112.246:10900
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

I tried to add nodeport like below, but it's not saving it. What is wrong?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "ignite.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ include "ignite.fullname" . }}
spec:
  ClusterIP:
  ports:
    - name: jdbc
      port: 11211
      targetPort: 11211
    - name: spi-communication
      port: 47100
      targetPort: 47100
    - name: spi-discovery
      port: 47500
      targetPort: 47500
    - name: jmx
      port: 49112
      targetPort: 49112
    - name: sql
      port: 10800
      targetPort: 10800
      nodedport: 30008
    - name: rest
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: thin-clients
      port: 10900
      targetPort: 10900
  selector:
    app: {{ include "ignite.fullname" . }}
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: At this example (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/) it is defined the `containerPort` and you dont have it. Also please try to run the command `kubectl describe ...` in order to show a detailed question, otherwise it is very dificult to help you :).

Comment: thnks for response :) added describe svc for ignite

Comment: It looks like you are using [headless-services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services). Try actually configuring [nodeport service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport). Let me know if you have any problems

Comment: can I use in addition to this nodeport as well? for example I want to connect with jdbc from my local compute and from kubentes vm

Comment: I added how I try to enable node port which now work can you please assist

Comment: "I tried to add nodeport like below but its not saving it" - Did you use `kubectl edit` to do it? If so, you need to know that you can't use edit because some fields are immutable. You need to recreate a service.

Comment: And also you need to remove `clusterIP: None` because it can't be None for NodePort. If you get any errors and don't know how to address them, please paste them here. It would be much easier for me to help you.

Comment: first thank you for helping, second it still not working  ( maybe its important also for you to know that its a statfullstate chart), the  service.yaml is above and this is the error I got: Error: UPGRADE FAILED: Service "ignite" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable

Comment: `Invalid value: "": field is immutable` - this means you can't just update a service. You need to recreate it. Try running helm with `--force` flag

Comment: Great. I summarized our discusion and provided the answer. I hope I didn't miss anything. Feel free to leave an upvote/accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize our discussion on comments:

The solution was to change [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) to [Nodeport Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport).

The problem was that edit of a service resulted in error because some service's fields are immutable (error: `Invalid value: "": field is immutable`). Service had to be recreated.

The solution was to use `--force` flag with helm.

```
> helm upgrade --help | grep force
--force        force resource updates through a replacement strategy
```